# Javascript (extjs) : check only one checkbox from two

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, extjs

The application I am working on is based on ExtJS, and what I would like to do is to allow the use to check only one checkbox.

The thing is that my application is very complex, and I don't really know a lot on ExtJS. The checkbox is initialized in a class viewport.js like this :

```
Ext.define('Viewport', {
    extend : 'Ext.container.Viewport',
    require : ['A','B'],
    frame : true,
    layout : 'fit',
    items : [{
                xtype : 'container',
                layout : 'hbox',
                margins : "a b c d",
                items : [{
                    margins : "0 0 5 35",
                    name : 'box1',
                    inputValue : true,
                    xtype : 'checkbox',
                    id : 'box1-box-id',
                    boxLabel : "BOX 1"
                }
                ,{
                    margins : "0 0 5 35",
                    name : 'box2',
                    inputValue : true,
                    xtype : 'checkbox',
                    id : 'box2-box-id',
                    boxLabel : "BOX 2"
                }]
            }
})
```

I don't know how to modify this code to have the user checking only one of these checkboxes. Do I have to add a function in this class?

Comment: "extend : 'Ext.container.Viewport'," <-- are you sure in this?

Comment: Why don`t you use RadioGroup (https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/classic/Ext.form.RadioGroup.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various approaches how to do this, the most straightforward and explicit way to achieve this is to add [`listeners`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Checkbox.html#cfg-listeners) to the checkboxes:

On the first checkbox definition, add:

```
listeners: {
    change: function(checkbox, newValue) {
        if(newValue) { // if this checkbox is changed to "checked" state...
            checkbox.nextSibling().setValue(false); // uncheck next checkbox
        }
    }
}
```

On the second checkbox definition, add:

```
listeners: {
    change: function(checkbox, newValue) {
        if(newValue) { // if this checkbox is changed to "checked" state...
            checkbox.previousSibling().setValue(false); // uncheck previous checkbox
        }
    }
}
```

Of course this does not scale well if you have more than just a few checkboxes. But then, for more than a few checkboxes this usually is bad UX anyways and you want to rethink your application from a user PoV.